# Tychonoff space is embeddable

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove this theorem:
A topological space is a Tychonoff space iff it is embeddable in a compact Housdorff space. Thanks

Comment: In fact, you can check that any Tychonoff space $X$ embeds into a "cube" $[0,1]^I$ where $I$ is some index set. By Tychonoff's theorem, this cube is compact (in the product topology).  To find such an embedding, select a collection of continuous functions $\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$, $X \to [0,1]$, rich enough to separate points from closed sets. Since $X$ is Tychonoff, such a collection exists. For example, you could take them all. Now, define $f : X \to [0,1]^I$ by letting the map onto $i$th coordinate be $f_i$, and check this (continuous, by definition of the product topology) map is an embedding.

Answer (score 1):

If a topological space is embedded in a compact Hausdorff space, then it must be Tychonoff. Because a compact Hausdorff space is always Normal, and of course it is Tychonoff, and hence the subspace is also Tychonoff.

A Tychonoff space is embedable in a compact Hausdorff space is a **famuous big theorem.**

You can refer books of general topology, for example, Kueen's book of general topology. Many books contain this theorem and its proof.